# calling variables within a custom function in r

Tags: r, function

I am learning how to write functions in r and something that has tossed me is how to call variables within a function

for example. I am aware that this code works for writing variables in ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data(iris)

func_test <- function(data, variable1, variable2){

ggplot(data, aes(x = {{variable1}}, y = {{variable2}}) +
geom_point()

}

func_test(df, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) # this code processes the variables without the need for a character string like with aes_string()
```

However when I write this next code, the output does not match how I expect it looks in ggplot

```
func_test2 <- function(var.name){

{{var.name}}

}

func_test2(testing) # this code does not write out the variable and instead tries to find the object. I just want to return the text output as is

# Error in func_test2(testing) : object 'testing' not found
```

Here is a specific example of my use case where I create a couple objects in R then write a function intended to reference different columns as variables within a formula.

```
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(gstat)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)

# in this example I use data from spData package to reproject a map of US states and interpolate total population in 2010 and 2015

data("us_states")
us_states <- st_transform(us_states, crs = 5070)

us_states[c('lon_m', 'lat_m')] <- us_states %>% 
  st_centroid(.$geometry) %>% 
  st_coordinates() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::select('lon_m' = X, 'lat_m' = Y)

us_states_centroid <- us_states %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() %>% 
  st_as_sf(., 
           coords = c('lon_m', 'lat_m'),
           crs = st_crs(us_states))

us_states_proj_grid <- us_states %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_make_grid(., cellsize = 10000, what = 'centers') %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>%
  cbind(., st_coordinates(.)) %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  mutate(., Z = 0)

raster <- rasterFromXYZ(us_states_proj_grid, 
                          crs = crs(us_states))

  
# I want to use this function and replace variable with different parameters (in this case total_pop_10 and total_pop_15), but R only reads my text as an object

func.var <- function(variable){
  
  model <- gstat(formula = eval(substitute(variable)) ~ 1, 
                 data = as(us_states_centroid, 'Spatial'),
                 nmax = 10, nmin = 3,
                 set = list(idp = 2))
  
  interpolate <- interpolate(raster, model)

interpolate
}

interpolation <- func.var(total_pop_15)

# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'total_pop_15' not found
```

My question to the forum is, how can I write a variable name to be read into a custom function as plain text like the example above?

Basically, I want to write custom functions that send text into other functions similar to how ggplot reads variables (compare aes() to aes_string()).

Answer (score 1):

You can create expressions with `substitute` and evaluate them with `eval`

Usually there's an easier way to do the thing you're trying to do without creating expressions in this way though. The `{{ }}` method only works for specific tidyverse function arguments, it's not an R-wide syntax.

```r
func_test2 <- function(var.name){
  x <- 3
  y <- 4

  eval(substitute(var.name))

}

func_test2(x) 
#> [1] 3
func_test2(y) 
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: See example above. When I try this method I still get the same error message